# IOS Custom UIViewController Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uikit

In my login screen of my Ios app I am trying to display a video. I saw on stack overflow a great example on how to do such thing. I tried the code out for myself and ran into an error. I was going to comment my error on the original post but my account did not have enough reputation to do so. My code when I run on my simulated device returns to me an error that says:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

(lldb)

I managed to track down there error using breakpoints to line 12 which is `avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: video!)`

Though here is my full code:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class VideoBackgroundController: UIViewController {
var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
var paused: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let video = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"space", withExtension: "mp4")
    //This is where my the error happens
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: video!)
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    avPlayer.volume = 0
    avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none

    avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                           object: avPlayer.currentItem)
}

func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
    let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    p.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    avPlayer.play()
    paused = false
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    avPlayer.pause()
    paused = true
}
}
```

And I do have a mp4 video named "space" in my project files.

[image: This is my project tree with my video]

Any explanation to how or why this is happening and what actions I can take to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check that your video file **space.mp4**  is listed under **Build Phase -> Copy Bundle Resources**. if not listed, add that and run your code.

Comment: Add the video  to your Xcode project
your project root > your Target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.

Your video MUST be here. If it's not, then you should add it using the plus button

Comment: @Surjeet That was the problem thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked and your code is running fine.

Just check that, the video should be under in your "Copy bundle Resources" of "Build Phases" tab in Target .

If it is not there , Please add the same as in below screenshots.

[image: Should be in Build Phases tab]

Comment: Thanks That Worked. One more question.. Sorry. My video that is being displayed is really zoomed in and not stretched to fit screen. Is there a way I can toggle that?

Comment: don't ask for upvote as per stackoverflow guidelines! @Myaaoonn

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning non optional value of video. Make it optional, ? Swift means – It can have a value, but it can also be nil. It is defined by “?”.Please look below code

```
avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: video?)
if avPlayer != nil
{ // Video url is not empty
}
else
{ // It is empty
}
```